# Creating an anonymous function and calling it passing arguments in one line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function-handle

You can do in matlab something like this:

```
>> fh = @(x) x^2
fh = 
   @(x)x^2
```

and then

```
>> fh(3)
ans =
    9
```

Now I look for a way to create the anonymous function and call it in one line, like this (it does not work):

```
@(x) x^2 (3) <-- This code does not work!
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason why `fh=@(x)x^2; fh(3)` is not a good enough solution? Doing `@(x) x^2 (3)` in one line, even if it was a valid syntax, is really equivalent to doing `3^2`. You are creating a function handle for no reason, since you are not storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 7):

`feval( @(x) x^2, 3)` is what you need.

Answer (score 6):

This would work (it works also with matrixes):

`arrayfun(@(x) x^2,3)`